# Mql4 Meta trader4, I can not make the indicator shift left simultaneously with the candles when new bar is formed

Tags: mql4

Below is the current code.
The indicator compiles and runs
When running the waves move with the candles as new bar forms.
But when you turn the platform off for some time and then turn it back on The candles and sin waves are now no longer synchronized.
Somehow the subwindow rests back to when the platform was turned on.
So no one out of 92 looky-loos wants to tackle this problem. I tried to put 3 pictures on here to help explain, but the system here will not display the pictures. If you are a coder trying to help, copy the code here, and paste it into your platform. Run it. Mark a high peak or low trough with a text symbol that will not move and then put a vertical line through the text character and the candle above it. as the program proceeds the vertical line will move with the candles and the wave moves with the vertical line, the text marker stays put so you can see where you started. Then turn off your platform with the indicator still loaded, wait for several candle periods then turn the platform back on and you will see that the waves reset back to the right. the vertical line continued on with the appropriate candle and the text marker also reset to the right with the peak or valley of the sin wave.

```
 //---- indicator settings
#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers 8 // 7
#property indicator_color1 Red
#property indicator_color2 Orange
#property indicator_color3 Yellow
#property indicator_color4 Lime
#property indicator_color5 Blue
#property indicator_color6 DodgerBlue
#property indicator_color7 DarkViolet
#property indicator_color8 White



//---- indicator buffers
double ExtBuffer1[], ExtBuffer2[], ExtBuffer3[], ExtBuffer4[], 
ExtBuffer5[],ExtBuffer6[], ExtBuffer7[], ExtBuffer8[];     
double Dgr1[], Dgr2[], Dgr3[], Dgr4[], Dgr5[], Dgr6[], Dgr7[], 
Dgr8[];
extern datetime StartTime=D'1999.11.10 00:00';

//+-------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function |
//+-------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
{
IndicatorBuffers(7); // 6
SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_LINE); SetIndexBuffer(0,ExtBuffer1); 
SetIndexShift(0,295);       
SetIndexStyle(1,DRAW_LINE); SetIndexBuffer(1,ExtBuffer2); 
SetIndexShift(1,264);     
SetIndexStyle(2,DRAW_LINE); SetIndexBuffer(2,ExtBuffer3); 
SetIndexShift(2,203); 
SetIndexStyle(3,DRAW_LINE); SetIndexBuffer(3,ExtBuffer4); 
SetIndexShift(3,166);      
SetIndexStyle(4,DRAW_LINE); SetIndexBuffer(4,ExtBuffer5); 
SetIndexShift(4,74); 
SetIndexStyle(5,DRAW_LINE); SetIndexBuffer(5,ExtBuffer6); 
SetIndexShift(5,102); // DodgerBlue
SetIndexStyle(6,DRAW_LINE); SetIndexBuffer(6,ExtBuffer7); 
SetIndexShift(6,78); // Dark Violet
SetIndexStyle(7,DRAW_LINE); 
SetIndexBuffer(7,ExtBuffer8); SetIndexShift(7,85); // White



   SetLevelValue(0,0);
   SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_LINE,0,3); // 0
   SetIndexStyle(2,DRAW_LINE,0,3); // 0
   SetIndexStyle(3,DRAW_LINE,0,3); // 0
   SetIndexStyle(4,DRAW_LINE,0,3); // 0
   SetIndexStyle(5,DRAW_LINE,0,3); // 0
   SetIndexStyle(6,DRAW_LINE,0,3); // 0
   SetIndexStyle(7,DRAW_LINE,0,3); // 0





return(0);
}
//+-------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Accelerator/Decelerator Oscillator |
//+-------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
{
   int limit; //  -----------------------------mine

   int counted_bars=IndicatorCounted();
//---- last counted bar will be recounted
   if(counted_bars>0) counted_bars--;
   limit=Bars-counted_bars;
   //-----------------------------------------mine  

   int Shift;
   int i;
   int b; // mine
   Shift=iBarShift(Symbol(),PERIOD_CURRENT,StartTime);
   ArrayResize(Dgr1,Shift+1); 
   ArrayResize(Dgr2,Shift+1); 
   ArrayResize(Dgr3,Shift+1); 
   ArrayResize(Dgr4,Shift+1);
   ArrayResize(Dgr5,Shift+1); 
   ArrayResize(Dgr6,Shift+1); 
   ArrayResize(Dgr7,Shift+1); 
   ArrayResize(Dgr8,Shift+1);

   MyCalc(Shift,1);

   for(b=Shift; b<limit; b++) // mine
  { 
   for(i=Shift; i>=0; i--) // >
   {
      ExtBuffer1[i]=Dgr1[i];
      ExtBuffer2[i]=Dgr2[i];
      ExtBuffer3[i]=Dgr3[i];
      ExtBuffer4[i]=Dgr4[i];
      ExtBuffer5[i]=Dgr5[i];
      ExtBuffer6[i]=Dgr6[i];
      ExtBuffer7[i]=Dgr7[i];
      ExtBuffer8[i]=Dgr8[i];






   }
  } // mine
return(0);
}
//+-------------------------------------------------------------+
void MyCalc(int Shift, int Yhigh )   
{
   int i;
   for(i=Shift;i>=0;i--)
   {
      Dgr1[i]=i*2.5; Dgr2[i]=i*2.5; Dgr3[i]=i*2.5; Dgr4[i]=i*2.5; 
      Dgr5[i]=i*2.5;

      double val1=i*2.5;
      double val2=i*2.5;
      double val3=i*2.5;
      double val4=i*2.5;
      double val5=i*2.5;
      double val6=i*2.5;
      double val7=i*2.5;
      double val8=i*2.5;


      Dgr1[i]=MathSin(3.14159*val1/298)- 1/2 * Yhigh;
      Dgr2[i]=MathSin(3.14159*val2/149)- 1/2 * Yhigh;
      Dgr3[i]=MathSin(3.14159*val3/98)- 1/2 * Yhigh;
      Dgr4[i]=MathSin(3.14159*val4/75)- 1/2 * Yhigh;
      Dgr5[i]=.5*MathSin(3.14159*val5/60)- 1/2 * Yhigh;
      Dgr6[i]=.5*MathSin(3.14159*val6/48)- 1/2 * Yhigh;
      Dgr7[i]=.5*MathSin(3.14159*val7/42)- 1/2 * Yhigh;                                                                      
      Dgr8[i]=.5*MathSin(3.14159*val8/38)- 1/2 * Yhigh;

   }
    }
```

Comment: You calculations are not linked to the candles so what makes you think they would shift?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking... The Sin waves do shift with the candles perfectly when the platform is running.  It is only when you turn the platform off or turn off the computer and then turn the computer back on and reload the platform that the sin waves are no longer in synch with the candles. The sin waves reset back to the right where they originally started. I tried to upload some pictures to this dialog but the pictures end up blank. Once manually set up the sin waves and candles must stay in synch. in order to see the entry and exit points of any trade potential.

Comment: Thanks again for your interest PaulB.

Comment: I am sorry but this Stack Overflow program will NOT let me add pictures to show what the indicator is doing. I have spent the last 4 hours trying to upload 3 pictures that could help those interested see what the indicator is doing.

Comment: Try using and link to [PrivateBin](https://privatebin.support-tools.com/)

Comment: The above problem with the indicator resetting has not been solved. So can someone post a link to a simple indicator and source code ( sub- window ) that extends the indicator, moving average, or sin wave to the right of candle zero? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to extend the sin wave to the right of candle zero other tbeb using the shift function?  I believe it is the Shift function that is causing the problem of resetting the wave back to its original start point when the computer is turned off or the platform is turned off and then turned back on.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the indicator starts drawing at `D'1999.11.10 00:00'`, however as this date is no doubt not available in your visible chart history, the indicator instead starts redrawing as the earliest available bar. This continues as you run the indicator, however when restarting MQL4, the visible bars is limited by your settings (Tools>Options>Charts>Max bars in chart) and upon reloading the indicator again reverts to start drawing at the earliest available bar which has now changed. As stated in my original comment, your calculation are not directly linked to candles so they will not shift consistently. If you wish to make them consistently, make the start point consistent somehow.

Comment: I have no idea how to accomplish that, I have tried a bazillion different approaches.  FYI, I am a 70-year-old male retired.  I am trying to learn this mql4 language to supplement my SSA. The mql4 help manual is about the worst written help manual I have ever encountered.  I have been trying a new approach by writing a new coded indicator that is less cumbersome and easier to read. but it is showing the same results as the above code and resetting the waves back to the starting point. I could learn Japanese from a Greek-speaking Eskimo translated through a Russian translator faster.

Comment: --------------------------------------------- Fresh start over -------------------------------

Ok, so the above problem and question has no answer or no one wants to answer. Then is it possible to plot a sine wave in a subwindow that starts somewhere on the left side of candle zero and continues to the right of candle zero on out to infinity.. it just keeps plotting the wave as the candles advance.? Also without using the shift function. The shift function just messes things up.

Comment: Wish I had something to announce on this problem... I know it is possible because there are at least 3 commercial Mt4 indicators on the market that do exactly this... I have one, but it does not extend to the right past candle zero, the others do.  I do not have the source code to see how they do it. The others are way too expensive.

Comment: It has been a while since I checked this site. Still, no solution has been posted. I know it can be done because one on the market does the same thing I am asking about. There has to be a coder that knows the answer out there somewhere.